# Variance of unspecified product distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance, covariance

Does there exist any general rule describing how the covraince between two **dependent** and **unspecified** stochastic variables, X and Y, affects the variance of their product disitrbution (XY)?

For simplicity, assume that E[X] and E[Y] are both positive. Additionally, assume existence of all relevant moments.

By the definition of a covaraince, it is straightforward to show that
$$
E[XY]= E[X]E[Y] + \text{Cov}[X,Y]
$$
Thus, a negative covariance reduces the expected value of the product disitrbution.

However, the variance seems less trivial. According to [Borhrnstedt and Golberger (1969)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286081), the variance can be expressed as
$$
V[pq] = E^2[X] V[Y] + E^2[Y] V[X] + 2E[X] E[Y]\text{Cov}[X,Y]-\text{Cov}^2(X,Y) \\
    + E[(\Delta X)^2(\Delta Y)^2] + 2E[X] E[(\Delta X)(\Delta Y)^2] + 2E[Y] E[(\Delta X)^2(\Delta Y)]
$$
with $\Delta X = X-E[X]$ and $\Delta Y = Y-E[Y]$.

The effect of the covariance between X and Y on the variance of the product disitrbution (XY) still seems unclear to me, as the last four terms can be expanded to include Cov[X,Y] in addition to cross-moments. This issue can be solved by asusming specific disitrbutions, but I would like a more general result for two **unspecified** disitrbutions.

Comment: Hello. Considering that the presented formula is valid, the only terms that have quantities evaluated by the two variables are $+2E[X]E[Y]Cov[X,Y]$ and $−Cov^2[X,Y]$. When the covariance is negative, both terms are negative, thus, the variance decrease (compared with the case with null covariance).  For positive covariance, it is a little more complicated, because you need to know the expectations $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ in order to tell whether $+2E[X]E[Y]Cov[X,Y −Cov^2[X,Y]$  is positive, negative or zero.

Comment: While a agree with the observations, @RenatoFernandes, it should be noted the effects from the covarainces imbedded in the last four terms of variance-equations are not accounted for. Recall from my post: "*The effect of the covariance between X and Y on the variance of the product disitrbution (XY) still seems unclear to me, **as the last four terms can be expanded to include the Cov[X,Y] in addition to cross-moments**.*"

Comment: you are right. I did not notice the squared terms. Sorry.